# sql Date function for the first Monday

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select

I want to write a ORACLE SQL FUNCTION that I pass the week number (Week of Year) and year like (3,2020) and the function return the first day (actually Monday) of this week.

Func1(3,2020) ---->

output: 13.1.2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by computing the first Monday of the year. This can be done using format specifier`'IW'` :

```
trunc(trunc(to_date(:year, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY'), 'IW')
```

You can then add the requested number of weeks:

```
trunc(trunc(to_date(:year, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY'), 'IW') + (:week - 1) * 7
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e054efcb3ce62e17156b44578240b9ea)**:

```
select trunc(trunc(to_date('2020', 'YYYY'), 'YYYY'), 'IW') + (3 - 1) * 7 res from dual
```

```
| RES       |
| :-------- |
| 13-JAN-20 |
```

You can easily put that code in a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN :weeknum = 1
           THEN
               TRUNC(to_date('01.01.'||:Year), 'yyyy')
           ELSE
               NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(to_date('01.01.'||:Year), 'yyyy') - 1, 'Son')
               + (:weeknum
                  - DECODE(
                        NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(to_date('01.01.'||:Year), 'yyyy') - 1, 'Son'),
                        TRUNC(to_date('01.01.'||:Year), 'yyyy'), 1,
                        2
                    ))
                 * 7
       END +1
           weekstart
  FROM DUAL;
```